# Partitions, $q$-polynomials and generating functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, power-series, partitions

Recall the [integer partition function](https://oeis.org/A000041) $P(n)$ with generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq0}P(n)x^n=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1-x^k}.$$
Let $[n]_q=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$ denote the $q$-analogue of the integer $n$ and let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)\vdash n$ be a partition of $n$. Now, define the function
$$\Psi_q(n)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\,\,\sum_{j\geq1}\,\, [\lambda_j]_q.$$
For example, $\Psi_q(3)=[3]_q+([2]_q+[1]_q)+([1]_q+[1]_q+[1]_q)=q^2+2q+6$. In particular, when $q=1$, we obtain $\Psi_q(n)=nP(n)$ with [generating function](https://oeis.org/A066186)
$$\sum_{n\geq1}nP(n)x^n=x\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1-x^k}.$$

I would like to ask

> **Question 1.** Is there a generating function for the sequence of $q$-polynomials $\Psi_q(n)$?
>
> **Question 2.** What is the combinatorial interpretation of the coefficients of $\Psi_q(n)$?

For example, the constant term of $\Psi_q(n)$ enumerates [the number of $1$'s](https://oeis.org/A006128) in all partitions of $n$.

Comment: Your link is for -Sum of all parts of all partitions of n.- maybe you want https://oeis.org/A006128 The constant term is the number of parts = number of parts greater than $0$,

Comment: It might be quite hard to find an ordinary differential equation for $\sum\Psi_q(n)z^n$, because it is already hard to find one for $\sum\Psi_1(n)z^n$. By contrast, it is "easy" (for a computer) to find such an equation for $\sum\Psi_1(n)/n z^n=\sum P(n) z^n$.  A q-differential equation might be a completely different story, but I could not find anything quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generating function of sorts is given by
  $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\Psi_q(n)x^n = P(x)\sum_{m\geq 0}q^m\sum_{k\geq m+1}
       \frac{x^k}{1-x^k}, $$
where $P(x)=\prod_{i\geq 1}(1-x^i)^{-1}$.

Comment: Maybe it's worthwhile to get rid of the second summation: $\frac{P(x)}{1-q}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1-q^k}{1-x^k}x^k$

Comment: @MartinRubey: your formula is certainly more elegant, while mine shows directly what is the coefficient of $q^m$.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure whether the rewriting has any merit.  It does have a plethystic feel.

Comment: I just realized that I should have written $P(x)\sum_k [k]_q \frac{x^k}{1-x^k}$, which makes its relation to $\sigma_0$, the number of divisors function (http://oeis.org/A000005), and $\sigma_1$, the sum of the divisors function (http://oeis.org/A000203), clear.

Answer (score 6):

I can answer part 2.

The co-efficient of $q^k$ in $\Psi_q(n)$ represents the number of elements greater than $k$ in all partitions of $n$

This can be proved with elementary analysis, mainly each part $k$ provides a contribution of $\{q^k,\dots,q^0\}$ to the q-nomial.

Part 1 is harder - both the differential of the partition function and the integral of the related [inverted partition function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=intregral%5B(1-x)(1-x%5E2)(1-x%5E3)(1-x%5E4)(1-x%5E5),%20%7Bx,-1,1%7D%5D) are unresolved I believe.

Comment: This coefficient sequence is http://oeis.org/A181187 with your interpretation along a comment about $k$th ranks (but nothing about the OP's $q$-analogues).

Comment: not sure - do you mean sum k-th parts = number parts >= k? @BrianHopkins

Comment: @BrianHopkins; first parts are in 1-1 with partition length?